# Get character from keycode

Tags: python

I get key code from KeyPressed event and I need somehow to generate a character from that key code. For example, user pressed 'A', I catch that event, get keycode and then I want to get back 'A' from keycode and write it somewhere.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Python-docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr

Anyways here's what you are looking for (assuming ASCII-code is what you ment):

```
keycode = 65
char = chr(keycode)
print char
```

Comment: This is not a key-code this is an ASCII code.

Comment: @Monster, I made a quick and simple assumption which lead me to believe that's what he actually needed. Which seems to have been the case since my answer was accepted.